# Mobile first application with Iframe in IOS

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

I have two application in mobilefirst . In my main application I added second application in Iframe.

The application URL's are somethig like this

```
Main application :http://localhost:10080/Mobile1/apps/services/preview/app1/common/0/default/index.html#/index.html

Sub application :
http://localhost:10080/Mobile2/apps/services/preview/app2/common/0/default/index.html#/index.html
```

I added sub application in main application with IFrame. Once the user is logged in my main application.I will store the user id in local storage and using this local storage userid to loggin the user into my sub application .

This function is working in browsers. But i created this hybrid application in IOS. That is not working properly.

My doubt is if we use local Storage in Main application.That cant be shared with the iframe in native app? any problem to get the local storage value to sub application. The main application and sub applications are under same base URL.

The problem is only existing in IOS  app.I didn't tested in android.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with saying this is a rather unorthodox way of displaying an application and I cannot say that MobileFirst supports this even if it "works" for you.

Secondly, the fact that as you point localStorage is not shared between the parent and child app indicates an issue that relates to the underlaying UIWebView provided by iOS - not MobileFirst.